# How to convert string date to GMT in java script?

Tags: javascript

This is my string date value `"2015-03-16T00:00:00"`

```
date.date = 2015-03-16T00:00:00
```

I need to convert it into the following format

```
Mon Mar 16 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Arabian Standard Time)
```

How i can do that?
p.s. i'm very new to java script.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way.

```
Date.setHours(0);
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Date.setHours is not a function`

Comment: try this it should work fine:   date = new Date();    date.setHours(0,0,0,0);

Answer (score 4):

```
var date = Date('2015-03-16T00:00:00');
console.log(date.toString()); // Mon Mar 16 2015 01:17:24 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

[Date documention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: data.Date = new Date(data.Date.toString()); 
The above code changes to "Mon Mar 16 2015 04:00:00 GMT+0400 (Arabian Standard Time)"
But i need to have "Mon Mar 16 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Arabian Standard Time)"